# Centering nodes with Tikz automatic node placement

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-graphs

I would like the nodes to be centered, an I can't see a way to do this:

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{graph}[grow down, branch right]
    {a -> {b,c}};
\end{graph}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an aside, the grow down option seems rather broken (just take out the branch right bit in the above). Is there a way to fix that?

**Note:** I want to do this with Tikz automatic node placement, not something else.

Comment: Centered in relation to what?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, so that `a` is x centered between `b` and `c`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I understand what is required, then you should take a look at the documentation (in the CVS manual) about graph layouts, in particular the `tree layout`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikz\graph [tree layout, grow down]
    {a -> {b,c}};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I do this in LaTeX? (Sorry if that was not implied from the question, its telling me I need LuaTex)?

Comment: @soandos I believe the new `graphs` library requires luatex. It's still LaTeX, but you have to compile with `lualatex` rather than `pdflatex`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. the rest of it seems to work fine without luatex. Is there a source for that? Additionally, compiling with lualatex gives me an error on `\usegdlibrary{trees}`

Comment: @soandos Sorry, I was a bit wrong, it's the `graphdrawing` library that requires LuaTeX. See the manual for the CVS version (ch. 27, Using Graph Drawing in TikZ).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. got it. This may be a silly question, but how much of the rest of my document do I have to change because of this? Also, how can I turn my document into a pdf? **NOTE:** Even compiling as luaLatex, it can't deal with \usegdlibrary

Comment: @soandos There's nothing in the code you posted that needs changing.  Don't know what you mean by the PDF comment, compiling with `lualatex` generates a PDF. I think you need a CVS version of TikZ to get the `graphdrawing` library, the current version in e.g. TeX Live does not have it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Already have a CVS version of tikz. Any thoughts on the `\usegdlibrary{tree}` line?

Comment: @soandos Don't know, haven't got a CVS-version myself, perhaps it was only recently added. Mark would have to answer that one.

Comment: @soandos Provided `\usegdlibrary{trees}` comes _after_ `\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}`, the order of the library inclusion isn't important. You _must_ compile with `luatex` to take advantage of the full node placement algorithms via the different layouts. I don't think the default placement (without the layouts or `luatex`) takes account of the number of siblings in child nodes so I think the only other way to get the required positioning would be with the `\node {a} child { node {b} } child { node {c} };` syntax.

Comment: @MarkWibrow I simply took you MWE, and attempted to compile it. As LuaTex, it gave me an undefined error on line 1, as LuaLaTeX, it gave me an undefined error on line 4.

Comment: @soandos Sorry, I mean't with `lualatex`.  But it compiles without problem for me. Possibly your CVS `pgf` version is corrupt or needs updating.

Comment: @MarkWibrow It appears my version of pgf is broken somehow (getting  `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/nodes behind edges/.forward to' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` from pfg code files only when I try to use the graphdrawing library, I'll get back to you when I fix it.

Comment: After fixing my pfg version, it all worked great (though I did have to add `\usepackage[english]{babel}` to get it to compile)

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {a}
    child{node {b}}
    child{node {c}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->]
\node {a}
    child{node {b}}
    child{node {c}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,sibling distance=15em]
\node {a}
    child{node {b}}
    child{node {c}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A bit complicated when handling many children but i guess this is what you wanted. There are many style options for the distance between the children and the layout can be set with defining a style.

Comment: Please read the note. I wanted to do this specifically with automatic node positioning.